# The divs overlapping when minimizing the browser

Tags: html, asp.net, css

This is my two divs:

[image]

This is the screen:

[image]

when I minimuse the browser, this overlapping happens

[image]

what should I do please?

#### To make it clear

the left div size is keep static even when I mimizie the browser, that is why the right div becoems over the left div

#### Edit2

when i tried Ruddy's solution, I got this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a scroll instead? I think it's kind of ok that they do this. Scrolling in a menu seems worse.

Comment: what is overlapping, please provide the code

Comment: @Niklas I need them to be in the same size when they minimize, I mean they become smaller in the same size, got me?

Comment: @San I showed you the code in the question

Comment: I guess you have some padding and/or margin and/or border on the two divs. Try setting `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: @HerrSerker: box-sizing only works on modern browsers... if your target browser is new you can try it

Comment: @HerrSerker do you mean I have to put box-sizing: 40%? and border-box:40%

Comment: I don't get it, what's overlapping what? Be more clear with your question.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli No. `box-sizing` is the rule and `border-box` is the value

Comment: @Ruddy in the first picture, there was a space between the two tabs, in the second picture, the right div becomes above the left div

Comment: @HerrSerker I tried, still the same problem

Comment: Guys i edited the question, please take a look

Comment: I'm still not getting you. You just called them "tabs" then "div's". Tabs are what's in that little table at the top, "today" and "tomorrow" etc. Still not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: @Ruddy that was just a typo, i mean dives, the two DIVS overlapping, and the problem is the right div becomes above the left div because the left div size is keep static,

Comment: Because your using `position: fixed`? Give them both static sizes (one on the right can have min width - max width) and then set them to `inline-block` so when they don't fit together one will go under the other? That what you mean? Or just don't use `fixed`. Thats why the overlap.

Comment: @Ruddy if i removed the fixed from the right div, it doesn't appear on the right, but it appears over the left div. i am using fixed to make the right div exaxctly on the very right

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli What you have is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/UGmwL/). What you should have to stop the overlapping: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/UGmwL/1/). Or like [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/UGmwL/2/) Or like [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/UGmwL/3/) One of these must make sense.

Comment: @Ruddy let me try that on my code, and i will tell you what hppaneding

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I updated my comment, take a look at all of them. `fixed` is causing your problem. You need to remove it.

Comment: @Ruddy when I tried your solution, I got the image(i posted it in the question) please look that the right div does't go to the very right of the screen

Comment: @Ruddy the image might be missleading, there is a space on the right of the page

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I would need to see the code, please create a fiddle because I know this works. Some other code will be breaking it.

Comment: @Ruddy the fiddle doesn't work in my case because i am using asp.net and i can't post asp.net there, but I cam give you an access to my computer. please it is just a simple code you it won't take a much time from you, just 5 miutes

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I'm afraid I cant at the moment, I'm at work. You can recreate the problem in a fiddle then I can fix it. Until then there's nothing I can do. Sorry buddy.

Comment: @Ruddy I will try to do that, and then, I will tell you. thanks

Comment: @Ruddy i may found somethign interesting, but i have to ask you first, if the width is 578px, what is in percent ?

Comment: There is no way to tell that. It would totally depend on the users screen resolution etc...

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli ASP is not, what is shown in your Browser. We do not need the ASP-Code, but the HTML code, your ASP creates.

Answer (score 1):

Try min-width on the right hand container div.

E.g.

```
min-width: 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

***Well it can perfectly be solved via responsive design but one thing you can try is to use percentages(%) for most of the html elements to manage the element overlapping problem this may help you upto some extend otherwise responsive web design is the necessary solution !***